# vb.net project inputbox "ok" and "cancel"

Tags: vb.net, winforms

When I start my VB program an InputBox appears asking for a name and I would like that when I click "Cancel" it closes the program and when I click "ok" this gives me a MessageBox that says "Please enter your name to play " and return to the InputBox. What I mean is that if I don't enter a name and the box is empty I will be asked to write something and return to the InputBox.

Sorry about English, it's not my first language and I still practice it.

it could also be my code which is poorly constructed, don't hesitate to rewrite it.

Thanks for the help provided

Here is the program in question:

```
 Private Sub frmMenu_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
     
     While String.IsNullOrEmpty(strUser)
      
         Dim FullName As String = InputBox("Please enter your first and last name:", "Identity")

         If String.IsNullOrEmpty(FullName) Then
             
             MessageBox.Show("You have canceled the operation. The application will now close.", "Cancelation", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
             Application.Exit()
             Return 
         ElseIf FullName.Trim() = "" Then
             
             MessageBox.Show("Please write something to play.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
         Else
             
             strUser = FullName
         End If
     End While

     Me.Text = "Hello, " & strUser
 End Sub
```

Comment: you should use a Loginform, where  you can distinguish between OK And cancel as it is already all by default there

Comment: Just don't use `InputBox` for anything ever. Design your own dialogue that does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, if the field is left blank there is **no way at all** to distinguish between the Ok and Cancel button for an `InputBox`. Either way, the result is the same empty string. If you need this ability, you will need to use a different form.

In theory, the `InputBox()` function wraps a form or system dialog providing distinct `DialogResult` values, but the function discards that information and does not make it available.

Comment: I already have a form to create. to access the form it has an InputBox which appears before asking me my name. If I don't enter anything and I click on "OK" a message box appears telling me to enter my name. and I return to the inputbox.
Example: when you go to a site and it asks you to enter your username and password, but if you enter nothing and you "validate" it returns to the login page to identify you. I want to do the same thing but with VB.net

Comment: You'll have to make your own form, then. The InputBox will not do it.

Comment: You can use a custom input box from code at this location and just change the 3rd last line from "Return defaultVal" to "Return vbNullString". Then the return value will be "Nothing" in the case that Cancel is selected.

https://binaryworld.net/main/CodeDetail.aspx?CodeId=1036

`Dim s As String = ""
Do While s = ""
    s = InputDialog.InputBox("Type your name:", "Begin", "")
    If s Is Nothing Then Exit Do
    If s = "" Then MsgBox("Type your name or press Cancel")
Loop`